# How to add ERC-20 symbol and logo to UniSwap?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap

We’ve created an erc-20 token and deployed it on Eth mainnet and listed plus added liquidity and received the LP’s on UniSwap.
At the moment, on UniSwap,  we can only search for the token by its 0x... address.

Question: How can we add the token’s symbol( name) and logo on UniSwap in order to be able to search and display the token by name ( in addition to the 0x... address search). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the information here:

https://support.uniswap.org/hc/en-us/articles/7959226015629-Token-Lists-

It seems that they're not accepting any applications for the moment.

But if you're listed on other chains you can use other DEXes.